# How to start actual work with GitHub from scratch?

Tags: git, bash

[It's my first question ever on Stackoverflow, please, don't hit me, I'm a total beginner]. I have a task to do and I got instructions for how to do it. Sadly, the instructions I got, don't really work.

The instructions say:

1. Open terminal
2. Configure github (and then there is exact instruction that I should type

   ```
   git config --global user.name "name and surename" 
   git config --global user.email "email addres"
   ```
3. Change editor from VIM:

   ```
   git config --global core.editor notepad 
   git config --global format.commitMessageColumns 72
   ```
4. Find a space on the drive into which I want to clone the repo. They suggest a folder "prework" located in the desktop.

What I get is this:

```
HP@PC MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ git config --global user.name "My-Name-Here"

HP@PC MINGW64 ~ (master)

$ git config --global user.email "My-Name-Here@gmail.com"

HP@PC MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ git config --global core.editor notepad

HP@PC MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ git config --global format.commitMessageColumns 72

HP@PC MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ cd prework
bash: cd: prework: **No such file or directory**

HP@PC MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ C:\Users\HP\Desktop\prework
bash: C:UsersHPDesktopprework: command not found

HP@PC MINGW64 ~ (master)
$
```

I have a feeling that I haven't done something very basic, in the very beginning. As you can see, I'm not even getting any reaction from the terminal. Is it normal? Is it okay?

Comment: You do get a reaction: it says that the `prework` directory doesn't exist. Do you ever create it, or `git clone` to get an existing project?

Comment: I think u will have to create folder by yourself on desktop . after that u can clone it inside the folder.

Comment: I did create a folder "prework" on my desktop, and made sure that the name is written in small letters (as I think it matters).

Comment: You are apparently already in a git repo, as it shows the branch ("master") in your prompt. Without knowing how you created it, it's hard to see what happens - but unless your home directory (`~`) is your desktop, the `prework` directory won't be there.

Comment: Okay, the thing is, it's a school project. They made us create our accounts on GitHub and then added us to their repo. What I did was: 1. Got added to the repo, 2. Do the procedure mentioned in the initial post 3. somewhere in the meantime I clicked "fork" in the repo, 4. Somewhere in the meantime I created a folder "prework" in my desktop. What do you mean by "but unless your home directory (~) is your desktop, the prework directory won't be there."

Comment: So, the folder "prework" should be in my home directory? What is that? How do I put "prework" to a home directory?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found the answer. A friend told me to type "ld" to check all the files in current directory, and then try

```
HP@PC MINGW64 ~ (master)
$ cd Desktop

HP@PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop (master)

$ cd prework

HP@PC MINGW64 ~/Desktop/prework (master)
$
```

This worked :-)